# CSS: Mantener estilo al romper la palabra

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Al romper la palabra con `word-wrap: break-word;` me gustaría que el border top se mantuviera, hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

Muchas gracias.

```css
td{
border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.width1{
width:60%;
display:inline-block;
word-wrap:break-word;
}
.width2{
width:30%;
}
.width3{
width:10%;
}
@media (max-width: 700px){
.width1{
width:20%;

word-wrap:break-word;
}
.width2{
width:60%;
}
.width3{
width:20%;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<table>
  <tr class="fila1">
  <td class="width1">holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
  <td class="width2">2</td>
  <td class="width3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila2">
  <td class="width1">1</td>
  <td class="width2">2</td>
  <td class="width3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila3">
  <td class="width1">1</td>
  <td class="width2">2</td>
  <td class="width3">3</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: No hay ningún `margin-top` ni `overflow-wrap: break-word;` en el código que has facilitado.

Comment: @Flowen ya esta la pregunta actualizada

Comment: El `word-wrap` no está causando el fallo, sino el `display:inline-block;`. Pruéba a quitarlo y mira como el borde es continuo.

Comment: Lo se, pero si no pongo el display:inline-block, depende de en que navegadores la palabra no se rompe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para mantener el borde lo más sencillo es aplicárselo a la fila en lugar de a las celdas:

```css
tr{
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.width1{
  width:60%;
  display:inline-block;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
.width2{
  width:30%;
}
.width3{
  width:10%;
}
@media (max-width: 700px){
  .width1{
    width:20%;

    word-wrap:break-word;
  }
  .width2{
    width:60%;
  }
  .width3{
    width:20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<table>
  <tr class="fila1">
  <td class="width1">holaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
  <td class="width2">2</td>
  <td class="width3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila2">
  <td class="width1">1</td>
  <td class="width2">2</td>
  <td class="width3">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="fila3">
  <td class="width1">1</td>
  <td class="width2">2</td>
  <td class="width3">3</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Buenas @AsierVillanueva me refiero a mantener el border-top pese a tener el break-word.

Comment: Entonces lo más sencillo es aplicárselo a la fila. He modificado la respuesta para mostrarlo

Comment: Mucho más sencillo así! Gracias!

Comment: Asier a ver si puedes darle un vistazo a este jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w52m5ggb/2/ en la tabla hago drag and drop, y al tener el display:inline-block, al hacer drag and drop se pone un estilo incorrecto.

Comment: Perdona, ahora si, mira este jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w52m5ggb/4/

Comment: No acabo de ver cual es el problema. Pero de todas formas entiendo que esto es mejor que lo plantees en una pregunta separada

Comment: Ya he formulado la pregunta, puedes mirarla cuando puedas :)